# How to use usb camera in qemu?

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, qemu

I am new in using the emulator qemu and I'm trying to make use of it to emulate the raspbian system, which is used in the raspberry pi, but I do not know how to use my camera usb in it. Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 7):

As of **October 2019** we now have `Qemu 4.1.0` and `-usbdevice` in [goe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34399643/5499166) is **deprecated**.

So, the advice is to use the new option `-device usb...` and probably your camera is `high-speed` so you must use `usb-ehci`, otherwise you'll get a `speed mismatch` error.

That said, I launch a VM with the integrated Webcam from my laptop with:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 2048 -rtc base=localtime -hda /path/win7.img -cpu host -soundhw hda -usb -device usb-ehci,id=ehci -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=3
```

`hostbus=1,hostaddr=3` is from:

```
lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:2fb1 Quanta Computer, Inc.
...
```

and I know that from:

```
sudo dmesg |grep -i webcam
...
[ 5594.955703] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_2HDM (0408:2fb1)
...
```

Comment: For me even though `lsusb`  output is like `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:57d6 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HP Truevision HD` I had to use ` -device usb-ehci -device usb-host,hostbus=0,hostaddr=4 \` and only then it worked.
I don't know why `hostbus=1` does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

To include the usb device, you can use the option '-usbdevice' and include the location of the device bus. The full option could be something similar to this:

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb ... -usbdevice host:5.4
```

The host address definition (I mean, the numbers after 'host:') could be found with 'lsusb' command. In the list given by 'lsusb' you have to find the device to be shared. For example:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 046d:0805 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C300
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2109:3431  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

In the previous example, the device I wanted to share is the 'Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920' camera, and as you can see in the corresponding line, the bus and device values are defined there (5 and 4 respectively).